# Passing values to controller using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Actually i have a table with multiple columns,the first column (ID) is hyperlink. So whenever the user click the hyperlink, the value should pass to controller and open the corresponding page in new window.

**My Script to open a page in new window**

```
 <script>
     function openInNewWindowWithSettings() 
{        
     window.open('@Url.Content("~/ConfirmVisit/ClaimDetails")', target = '_blank', width = '1000px', height = '800px');        
}
```

**Table data**

```
 <tr>
  <td><a href='javascript:openInNewWindowWithSettings();'>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClaimID)</a></td>
 </tr>
```

i tried this approach, but the values are not passing to controller and open a new window with empty page.

So how can i change my code to get the value of id to controller?
Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Refer the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) - the first parameter is the url (which needs to be the value of the `href` attribute of your link

Comment: @StephenMuecke i made some changes in my script,and passed the url as first parameter. But when i tried to pass the ClaimID. The script not working.

Comment: Its not `Url.Content()` - its `Url.Action()` and if you want to pass a parameter then the format to build the url is `@Url.Action("ClaimDetails", "ConfirmVisit", new { id = "item.ClaimID" })`

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke, its working now. But still its not taking the correct Id. It just takes the last row claimID for all the rows.

Comment: OKay @StephenMuecke, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate you `<a>` tags inside your loop using `@Url.Action()` to generate the correct url for each `Claim` and add it as a `data-*` attribute

```
@foreach(var item in ....)
{
    <td>
        <a href="#" class="claim-link" data-url="@Url.Action("ClaimDetails", "ConfirmVisit", new { id = item.ClaimID })">@item.ClaimID</a>
    </td>
}
```

Then handle their `.click()` event of the link and extract the url

```
$('.claim-link').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    var attributes = "width=1000,height=800";
    window.open(url, "yourWindowName", attributes);
}
```

Refer also [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) for each of the 3 parameters to be pass to the `window.open()` function

Comment: its not working @Stephen Muecke. It just changes the url with the addition of # in the current page

Comment: But 'target = '_blank'' will open in new tab...i am expecting to open in new window like how you mentioned before @Stephen Muecke

Comment: But did you actually use `window.open(url, "yourWindowName", attributes);` i.e. specify all the parameters correctly?

Comment: And I have just tested in Chrome and its working fine.

Comment: Can you please show how you passed the url @ Stephen Muecke. i used window.open(url, "yourWindowName", attributes);